# Working with String value in Build/Ant file in Java

Tags: java, ant, build.xml

I am unable to find the solution of working with String values in ant/build file. I have 2 values in 2 text field in java project. I need to pick up those two string (text fields) values to the build file.

**Example:-**

```
java.io.InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream() ;
                InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedrReader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);
                String strLine = "";
                int length = strLine.length();
                progressBar.setMaximum(100);
                length=progressBar.getValue();

                while ((strLine = bufferedrReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(strLine);
                    System.setErr(System.out);
                    String newline = "\n";
                    textArea.append(strLine+newline);
                    textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.SCROLLBARS_VERTICAL_ONLY);
                    length++;
```

*I have this code with a string. Where is this string value is stored so that i can use its value in ant file.*

**EDITED**

```
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Text Files","txt");
                JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Choose");
                fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter);

                // For Directory
                fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);

                int rVal  = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
                if (rVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                  textFieldChoose.setText(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().toString());
                    String str="";

                  final JFrame msgframe= new JFrame();
                  msgframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                  str= textFieldChoose.getText();
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(textFieldChoose, str);
```

*I want to read the value of `String str="";` outside any text file from where I  can use it in my build file. **str** is the path value of the selected file "?*

Comment: Post where you would like to use these `String`(s) in your build file (the relevant part of `build.xml`)? Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: I want those 2 string values to get combined. suppose string1= " C:\Program Files\Plugins\xyz.xzy.p" and string2= "C:\Program Files\Plugins\xyz.txt". So these 2 values is being combined in build.xml . I just want to know how these two path/values can be picked from the java project so that I can include it in build/ant file.

Comment: Can be picked from running the java project you haven't built? Please **clarify** your question.

Comment: I had added further process.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I got the answer , Thank You for your time.

Comment: @RohitGhosh remember to accept an answer when you have what you were looking for. If the answer you found is different that the one proposed, take the time to share it or delete this question if you think it will not interest other users.

Comment: @AxelH yes sure , thank you . I am not taking it  down. might get  interest to other user

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
 textArea.append(strLine+newline);
```

It looks like the code is appending the file content line by line to a [JTextArea](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) (or worse, an old AWT TextArea).

In any case, your code is simply updating an UI element.

In other words: all you got is already there. Just dont append the text read from the files to that UI component, but make it available to your ANT task!

Comment: Yes , I need to show it in UI , I had added further code

Comment: I got the answer , Thank You for your time.